# openlayer3 map can't display well on my website

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

i use openlayer3  to make a map. it can display on my local computer perfectly,but it can't display on the website when i put this map into my server.what's the problem? my code is like:

```
  var style1 = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 1)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#c0c0c0',
        width: 1
    }),
    /*text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
           color: '#fff',
           width: 3
        })
    })*/
});
var vectorLayer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'data/bg.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
        extractStyles: false
    })
}),
style: style1
});
var map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
layers: [
    vectorLayer1
]
```

Comment: Does your website support the geojson mime type?

Comment: Thanks.I've found this problem.